# USB device causing Windows 8 computer to become unresponsive

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, freeze

I am trying to diagnose an issue with a Windows 8 PC where all USB devices attached to a computer cease working, making the computer appear like it is frozen. However a remote user can still interact with the PC normally (Opening administrative share, sharing a remote session with the device.)

I have identified that the device in question (A secugen thumb scanner) is the cause. When removed and the computer is used for a day the PC does not freeze. The next day when it is plugged in (But not always used.) then the PC will freeze, but remain responsive to remote connections.

I have tried the following so far:

- Update and rollback to various versions of the drivers.
- Plug USB into a seperate USB controller (Rule out excessive power consumption & IRQ problems, even though that should not be a problem in this modern day)
- Attempt to replicate the problem by using the device, but appears to happen randomly throughout the day.
- Identify possible links in the event log, nothing out of the ordinary appears yet during the freeze times.
- Used a spare from 1 of 4 other PCs with the same thumb scanner on this computer but still crashed.
- Used the thumb scanner on one of the other PCs, did not crash.

The difference between this computer and the other 4 is that this computer is an active windows work station, the others are just smaller machines who's sole purpose involves thumb scanning, there's less to go wrong on them!

My question is has any one come across something similar or know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Does this device cause any other computers to malfunction?

Comment: No, I'll edit to clarify. There are 4 other PCs which the same thumb scanners. We used another thumb scanner from one of those PCs and the crash still occurred, but the crash didn't occur when we used the original in one of the other computers.

Comment: Are they by chance USB 3.0? I've had troubles on my personal desktop where a USB 3.0 device will begin to interrupt mouse movement and the keyboard.